# Python (ML) Linear Regression using 3 predictors for 1 target (quality)

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

**[I have done EDA on this white whine dataset and I am trying to find 3 predictors of quality and conduct linear regression on them.](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/wine+quality)**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

wine = "~/Desktop/datasets/winequality-white.csv"
# Load the data
df = pd.read_csv(wine,sep=";")
df.head()

# Look at the information regarding its columns.
df.info()
# non-null floats also validated by √null_release_mask = df['fixed 
acidity'].isnull()
```

> I'm trying to Do a train-test split and choose 3 predictors to predict quality

```
 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

 X = df[["alcohol", "pH","free sulfur dioxide"]]
 y = df["quality"]

 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, 
 test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

 print(len(X_train), len(X_test))
 print(len(y_train), len(y_test))`
 from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

 model = LinearRegression()

 model.fit(X_train,y_train)


import numpy as np

x_values_to_plot = np.linspace(0, df[["alcohol", "pH","free sulfur 
dioxide"]].max(), 15)
y_values_to_plot = (x_values_to_plot * model.coef_) + model.intercept_

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))

ax.scatter(df[["alcohol", "pH","free sulfur dioxide"]], df["quality"], 
label="data", alpha=0.2)
ax.plot(x_values_to_plot, y_values_to_plot, label="regression_line of 
white wines", c="r")
ax.legend(loc="best")

plt.show()
```

> However I get this error :

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call 
 last)
<ipython-input-68-c52d735932ab> in <module>()
  1 import numpy as np
  2 
----> 3 x_values_to_plot = np.linspace(0, df[["alcohol", "pH","free 
sulfur dioxide"]].max(), 15)
      4 y_values_to_plot = (x_values_to_plot * model.coef_) + 
model.intercept_
      5 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/function_base.py in 
linspace(start, stop, num, endpoint, retstep, dtype)
    122     if num > 1:
    123         step = delta / div
--> 124         if step == 0:
    125             # Special handling for denormal numbers, gh-5437
    126             y /= div

 *ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element 
 is 
  ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()*
```

> Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am new to StackOverflow so have mercy over the format of question & let me know on what I can improve. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This particular error pertains to this snippet

```
x_values_to_plot = np.linspace(0, df[["alcohol", "pH","free sulfur dioxide"]].max(), 15)
```

Since

```
df[["alcohol", "pH","free sulfur dioxide"]].max()
```

Will return three values, the max for alcohol, pH and free SO2.  You can fix this by adding another .max() which will select the max of those three max values, assuming this is what you are trying to do.

You have a few other issues with the section below your regression model.  What exactly do you want to present at the end?  You could always try using seaborn, which is good for these types of visualisation.